# question on simple groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, automorphism-groups

Let $G$ be a simple finite group. Then every non trivial endomorphism of $G$ is an automorphism. My question is: does the converse holds? More precisely, if $G$ is a finite group all of whose non trivial endomorphisms are automorphisms, is $G$ simple?

Comment: Note that this implies that $G$ is a perfect group. The smallest order of a non-simple non-trivial perfect group is 120, namely the binary icosahedral group. This is precisely the example provided in the answers.

Answer (score 5):

No, that does not hold and it's very easy to find counterexamples. For example $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_q)$ is non-simple, because it has a non-trivial (for $q>2$), proper, normal subgroup, namely its center $\{\pm1\}$, and that is in fact its *only* non-trivial, proper, normal subgroup for $q>3$. This also means that every non-trivial endomorphism is injective, because $\{\pm1\}$ cannot be its kernel. If it were, $PSL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ would embed into $SL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ as a subgroup of index two which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

No. The group $PSL(2,5)$ is simple and is the only proper non-trivial quotient of $SL(2,5)$. It is also not a subgroup of $SL(2, 5)$. So $SL(2,5)$ is not simple but every non-trivial endomorphism of it is an isomorphism.